# unable to create log file

Tags: wpf, logging, mvvm, prism

I am using below code for creating logging in my project using PRISM ILoggrFacade.
But i am not sure is the best way and second thing how can i use CustomLogger class logging because i am unable to create logging.

```
public class CustomLogger : ILoggerFacade
    {

        protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CustomLogger));
        public CustomLogger()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }

        public void Log(string message, Category category, Priority priority)
        {
            switch (category)
            {
                case Category.Debug:
                    log.Debug(message);
                    break;
                case Category.Warn:
                    log.Warn(message);
                    break;
                case Category.Exception:
                    log.Error(message);
                    break;
                case Category.Info:
                    log.Info(message);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Bootstrapper**

```
 private readonly CustomLogger _logger = new CustomLogger();
 protected override ILoggerFacade CreateLogger()
        {
            return _logger;
        }
```

**ViewModel**

```
            logger.Log("Logging success", Category.Info, Priority.None);
```

**log4net.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\temp\log.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: First of all, don't use the `ServiceLocator` for obtaining the logger. Service locator is considered to be an anti-pattern if you're not implementing a DI container by yourself. And second: what is your **particular** question actually?

Comment: @dymanoid unable to create log file

Comment: Wha texactly goes wrong? Do you get an error? Does the code go through but the file doesn't get created? Do you get an exception somewhere?

Comment: @Metallkiller now i was able to create log file..actually i am configuring my xml in constructor...but file created once i have to specify "[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4Net.config", Watch = true)]" in assembly

Comment: @Metallkiller now i am wondering how to use logging in different modules i am using  unity .Any Idea ?

Comment: @stylishCoder No idea, I have neither worked with prism before, nor with unity :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem with above code is that need to configure log4net in assembly like below:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

**Also in addition if you wan to drag log4net in ViewModels the use below code**

```
 private readonly ILoggerFacade _loggerFacade;
 public ContentAViewViewModel(ILoggerFacade loggerFacade)
        {
          _loggerFacade = loggerFacade;
        }
```

**Example**

```
    private void LoadPeople()
        {
        _loggerFacade.Log("Load People", Category.Debug, Priority.High);
        }
```